# PostgreSQL - lost configuration files

Tags: postgresql

I have been trying to reinstall postgresql-9.4, by:

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql postgresql-common postgresql-9.4 postgresql-contrib-9.4

sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-common postgresql-9.4 postgresql-contrib-9.4
```

This, unfortunately results in a empty `/etc/postgresql` directory. How can I get these configuration files back?

Comment: You should use `remove` instead of `purge` ([manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/apt-get.8.html)) if you want to keep the config (user specific config in home directory is kept even when you use purge to uninstall an application though). Just saying for future reference ... hopefully someone else will help you restore the lost config...

Comment: Thank you, I'll use remove next time! I don't need to restore the exact same configuration files, just get some inside the /etc/postgresql directory!

Comment: Take them from the backup.

Comment: obviously I have no backup!

Comment: Obviously, now you will start making them! :-D

Comment: Sure! But that does not help me right now ;)

Answer (score 0):

After a purge and install, default config files should've been created for you. It is odd that that is not the case.

Use

```
pg_createcluster 9.4 main
```

to create a new Pg cluster and config files.